# ApplicationPool randomically crash handling HTTPS request

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, crash-dumps

I have an issue with an ASP.NET site running in a IIS (10.0.14393.0) on Windows Server 2016.

Randomically, the page I opened in the browser (only when I open with HTTPS) return me error:

[image]

I have then searched on the Windows Server, looking for meaningfull log about the error.

What I have found is that every time I get that error, the application pool associated with that page crash.

In the windows event log I have those logs two error (they appear every time with that order):

```
Name of the application that generated the error: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, timestamp: ------
Name of the module that generated the error: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.14393.2457, timestamp: ------
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Error offset ------------
Process ID that generated the error: ------
Start time of the application that generated the error: ------------
Path of the application that generated the error: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Path to the module that generated the error: C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
Report ID: ------------
Full package name that generated the error:
Application ID for the package that generated the error:



Name of the application that generated the error: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, timestamp: ------
Name of the module that generated the error: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3986, timestamp: ------
Exception code: 0xe0434352

Error offset ------------
Process ID that generated the error: ------
Start time of the application that generated the error: ------------
Path of the application that generated the error: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Path to the module that generated the error: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: ------------
Full package name that generated the error:
Application ID for the package that generated the error:
```

So i downloaded the dump file to better invetigate the crash, but i have not found nothing meaninful inside, here the content:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=------------
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=------------
IntegratorReportIdentifier=------------
NsAppName=w3wp.exe
AppSessionGuid=------------
TargetAppId=------------w3wp.exe
TargetAppVer=------------w3wp.exe
BootId=------------
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=w3wp.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=10.0.14393.0
Sig[2].Name=Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=------------
Sig[3].Name=Module name with errors
Sig[3].Value=KERNELBASE.dll
Sig[4].Name=Module version with errors
Sig[4].Value=10.0.14393.3986
Sig[5].Name=Timestamp module with errors
Sig[5].Value=------------
Sig[6].Name=Exception code
Sig[6].Value=e0434352
Sig[7].Name=Exception offset
Sig[7].Value=0000000000034f38
DynamicSig[1].Name=Versione SO
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.14393.2.0.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=ID localsetting
DynamicSig[2].Value=------------
DynamicSig[22].Name=Add info 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=------------
DynamicSig[23].Name=Add info 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=------------
DynamicSig[24].Name=Add info 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=------------
DynamicSig[25].Name=Add info 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=------------
UI[2]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
UI[5]=Cerca una soluzione online (scelta consigliata)
UI[6]=Cerca una soluzione in un secondo momento (scelta consigliata)
UI[7]=Chiudi
UI[8]=IIS Worker Process ha smesso di funzionare ed è stato chiuso
UI[9]=Si è verificato un problema che impedisce il funzionamento corretto dell'applicazione. Se è disponibile una soluzione, si riceverà una notifica automatica.
UI[10]=&Chiudi
LoadedModule[0]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[9]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\iisutil.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[19]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wphost.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[22]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\nativerd.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\XmlLite.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ktmw32.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
LoadedModule[28]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\IISRES.DLL
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mscoree.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\iiscore.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[46]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\W3TP.dll
LoadedModule[47]=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3dt.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\HTTPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\loghttp.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachfile.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachtokn.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachhttp.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compstat.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\defdoc.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\dirlist.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\protsup.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\static.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authanon.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\modrqflt.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\custerr.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\isapi.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\filter.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\validcfg.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\redirect.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compdyn.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\ISAPI_Rewrite_x64.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\wbhst_pm.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\1fb5d602b6f8dd4b8d971ddbd1490fb3\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\a179960d666c10cfe020612d369c7500\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Core\638dd10e292e66ac3e90af4f89a827fe\System.Core.ni.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web\8e85d230b324c4df515541caa076ea1d\System.Web.ni.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.8dc504e4#\a79bf6b3640b1fc4c78ccd65c4d1fd72\System.Web.ApplicationServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Configuration\3bb1efb20a04c48ec01181ed018d1836\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xml\ee993503af20cdc60c6fa32fbb601a8b\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data\c3bdc749e7492f5d25a12761da2e771c\System.Data.ni.dll
LoadedModule[92]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Ente96d83b35#\e45a68b4a9d59480473ee8f4b03eb14f\System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[93]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Drawing\8dd89e176af68fe3335936a3d9d01803\System.Drawing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[94]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Comp46f2b404#\67c605f6b258ba9d0a33ed1a153d689a\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ni.dll
LoadedModule[95]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Dire5d62f0a2#\2c8f7c2a6659a1d07fcf71a3086cd7b6\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ni.dll
LoadedModule[96]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Dired13b18a9#\409d9d4d66085c7d955591ffbfe1fbfc\System.DirectoryServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[97]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.B83e9cb53#\7f0ef60d1372e81bc1f85e8d7e4e3ed6\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.ni.dll
LoadedModule[98]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runt19c51595#\d68dd07f45c16fe55503c29bd715eb2c\System.Runtime.Caching.ni.dll
LoadedModule[99]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.B3325a29b#\b13d4e4e246a72a5cbd13aa63d95eb27\Microsoft.Build.Framework.ni.dll
LoadedModule[100]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.82d5542b#\73fa1ff8e994a3ceec6d273102a95253\System.Web.RegularExpressions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[101]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Design\bd6f050fac8332f81ba468f3087d05ac\System.Design.ni.dll
LoadedModule[102]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Security\9e8b3734045148ed8ff5247edc4ad266\System.Security.ni.dll
LoadedModule[103]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Serv759bfb78#\f2e6426808704ca3166d3840157b6718\System.ServiceProcess.ni.dll
LoadedModule[104]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.Services\b2ef4e89c40e41ec391a6eeabb5e4f90\System.Web.Services.ni.dll
LoadedModule[105]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.Baa2ca56b#\bcd4d378cfcf4b2451f873c4f16d0df2\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.ni.dll
LoadedModule[106]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Windows.Forms\2a3b96667a4f390cf174997bceddb4a7\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
LoadedModule[107]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data.SqlXml\e8ac8292f12fae012b4c24720531a2a0\System.Data.SqlXml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[108]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Numerics\c461d167e98025cd29175c4fdb1e5e54\System.Numerics.ni.dll
LoadedModule[109]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Transactions\af9a9eba301e98fba0f64109f4a67187\System.Transactions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[110]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runt73a1fc9d#\9ab4baf18cca99016ebdff4af030ca73\System.Runtime.Remoting.ni.dll
LoadedModule[111]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xaml\9a352c1bc84ebd15b5d581c264621743\System.Xaml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[112]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Draw0a54d252#\c034f3d9d8245173ea5c518f70444f8a\System.Drawing.Design.ni.dll
LoadedModule[113]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Accessibility\c30914a3be37af1b997580570ac7675f\Accessibility.ni.dll
LoadedModule[114]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data86569bbf#\3fe958e19c5260c50ba0f6f048435176\System.Data.OracleClient.ni.dll
LoadedModule[115]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runt9064068c#\e0dd819676b895412003098f51de4ec4\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ni.dll
LoadedModule[116]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Confe64a9051#\24e554a594e6d42102c0c2e7576df6c2\System.Configuration.Install.ni.dll
LoadedModule[117]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Deployment\fca5ac748bf046cc2a800e16e9859fe1\System.Deployment.ni.dll
LoadedModule[118]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runteb92aa12#\1e64c7d17e2daf22a0f8287a42985ecc\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll
LoadedModule[119]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\SMDiagnostics\eaac3c82806c952f53cbab9ebce3d87e\SMDiagnostics.ni.dll
LoadedModule[120]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Servd1dec626#\ab425c8734f9f4e34c6e6f13f2aae73a\System.ServiceModel.Internals.ni.dll
LoadedModule[121]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[122]=C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll
LoadedModule[123]=C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[124]=C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[125]=C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[126]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.JScript\68086d4c1ee6ffed4b387ef262ea2ddc\Microsoft.JScript.ni.dll
LoadedModule[127]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.28b9ef5a#\4594384a0dfdf250e1c0c1821af00da1\System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[128]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.ServiceModel\a390b1e7674beadd924748ef751e1f6d\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
LoadedModule[129]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data.Linq\960a8c8701b75469434a15e282b19382\System.Data.Linq.ni.dll
LoadedModule[130]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Serv14b62006#\f7aef607ad719d851ba73fa9bcfc438f\System.ServiceModel.Activation.ni.dll
LoadedModule[131]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data16016462#\259afd5ea3e04141d53ab91edbdd3581\System.Data.Services.Design.ni.dll
LoadedModule[132]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data14bed3a9#\4292b1a6ef3aaa0be3d6c4b730025209\System.Data.Services.Client.ni.dll
LoadedModule[133]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Data.Entity\175b730d78a17e775d9cff21c71c5154\System.Data.Entity.ni.dll
LoadedModule[134]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.IdentityModel\7d99f2c5fcc237b1cb2f1fee9ed6f4e7\System.IdentityModel.ni.dll
LoadedModule[135]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.Te49ad7d9#\1429a6df2d610589da4c42ad9da01f34\Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.ni.dll
LoadedModule[136]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Messaging\39dff400218baf5cfa30210643e959d2\System.Messaging.ni.dll
LoadedModule[137]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Net.Http\02b925e77b9967b35414935d5da5eee1\System.Net.Http.ni.dll
LoadedModule[138]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runt93d54979#\08cee5b2b5599878f7037522727c7922\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[139]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Idena7b556ff#\376dffd3a64a916740eabc964111cfad\System.IdentityModel.Selectors.ni.dll
LoadedModule[140]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xml.Linq\3a35639f0bba30c8cc2cd56074aad87c\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll
LoadedModule[141]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xaml.Hosting\08fc5cbdcce042f75b775af891051893\System.Xaml.Hosting.ni.dll
LoadedModule[142]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Serv14259fd9#\7d02112876eed8997fc7e04fec437b79\System.ServiceModel.Activities.ni.dll
LoadedModule[143]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Activities\46dbc8d652bbfc2c0163d34432455b1d\System.Activities.ni.dll
LoadedModule[144]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Acti2661942e#\2310d7b1eec6787bf9200ae45053d99f\System.Activities.DurableInstancing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[145]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.Vf4833439#\c28839bb55394223f5c8b50ff6fc9cb9\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler.ni.dll
LoadedModule[146]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.V9921e851#\1fede9712af836675a98bf1d03927aa1\Microsoft.VisualBasic.ni.dll
LoadedModule[147]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Management\453c6c392055c1a635ed58e7c21a8b02\System.Management.ni.dll
LoadedModule[148]=C:\Windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[149]=C:\Windows\System32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[150]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[151]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll
LoadedModule[152]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.Mobile\e7b7a4debff76e2daf42196acbdfbbd8\System.Web.Mobile.ni.dll
LoadedModule[153]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
LoadedModule[154]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
LoadedModule[155]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
LoadedModule[156]=C:\Windows\system32\security.dll
LoadedModule[157]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SECUR32.DLL
LoadedModule[158]=C:\Windows\system32\schannel.DLL
LoadedModule[159]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mskeyprotect.dll
LoadedModule[160]=C:\Windows\system32\ncryptsslp.dll
LoadedModule[161]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\rasapi32.dll
LoadedModule[162]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\rasman.dll
LoadedModule[163]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\rtutils.dll
LoadedModule[164]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\winhttp.dll
LoadedModule[165]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ondemandconnroutehelper.dll
LoadedModule[166]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[167]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
LoadedModule[168]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrcompression.dll
LoadedModule[169]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
FriendlyEventName=Ha smesso di funzionare
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=IIS Worker Process
AppPath=c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=FCBB9E96A3E01E440E0E4D9368EBD4AC
MetadataHash=29496159
```

I have no idea of what to do to resolve that issue, so any hint is welcome.

Comment: "So i downloaded the dump file to better invetigate the crash"? You didn't do anything yet. If you don't know much on dump analysis, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

First please check the account under which worker process w3wp.exe is running have read/write permissions of your hosting folder(such as Inetpub folder), then delete project bin and obj folders and try again.

The Exception code 0xe0434352 is a generic CLR exception code. It is thrown when there is an internal issue in the application. In most cases, it is either System.NullReferenceException or System.ArgumentException. There is no straightforward way to solve these kind of issues. I would recommend debugging the application in Visual Studio to get more details. In case you don’t have access to the source code, you can use DebugDiag or WinDbg for further troubleshooting.

Comment: The w3wp process use ApplicationPool identity, and folder has the right privilege for that user.Additional info, after few testing i can assure that the problem occurred only with HTTPS (no error with HTTP) and only on certain machine (i try to deploy on different web server and by now i have got no problem)